# Q_DECLARE_METATYPE of `boost::posix_time::ptime`

Tags: c++, qt

I have registered`boost::posix_time::ptime` to QT using the following code

```
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(boost::posix_time::ptime);
```

However I still get the error

> Error 1   error C2338: Type is not registered, please use the
>   Q_DECLARE_METATYPE macro to make it known to Qt's meta-object system

Any suggestions??

Comment: You need to register them, not just declare. You should use `qRegisterMetaType` function. And `qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators` function for types that have streaming operators.

Comment: I tried both Q_DECLARE_METATYPE and qRegisterMetaType together but that did not help either. I got the same response

Answer (score 0):

Remember that `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` merely defines a specialization of `QMetaTypeId` for your type. It is only useful to the code that follows it, *in the same file*. It is meant to be put in a header where the given type is declared. So, if you had a custom type `FooType`, you'd put the `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` directly after the declaration, and in the global namespace.

So, what you'd ideally need to do is to modify your copy of boost and add the following at the end of `posix_time.hpp`:

```cpp
#if defined(QT_CORE_LIB) && !defined(Q_DECLARE_METATYPE)
#include <QMetaType>
#endif
#if defined(Q_DECLARE_METATYPE)
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(boost::posix_time::prime)
#endif
```

If you don't want to modify your copy of boost, then in **every file where you use this type**, you must add `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(boost::posix_time::prime)`. At the minimum, this must be every file that's processed by moc *and* uses the type! The code generated by moc will include the headers that moc has processed, and it is in those headers that the `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` declaration must be visible.

You may want to simply put it into a `my boost_posix_time.hpp` header, so that you won't forget to do so:

```
//myboost_posix_time.hpp
#include <QMetaType>
#include "boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp"
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(boost::posix_time::ptime)

//myobject.h
#include "myboost_posix_time.hpp"
#include <QObject>

class MyObject : public QObject {
  ...
  Q_SLOT void useTime(boost::posix_time::ptime);
  ...
};
```

You must also add `qRegisterMetaType<boost::posix_time::ptime>` in `main()`. Again, everywhere you use that type with the metatype system, you must have the `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE`.